Is the double adjoint operator $T^{''}$ of $T:E \to F$, with $E$ beeing reflexive, "equal"(up to isomorphism) to $T?$
Let $T:E\to F$ be a bounded, linear operator between the banach spaces $E,F$. The adjoint operator is defined as $T': F'\to E', y' \mapsto y' \circ T$, while $E',F'$ are the dual spaces resp.
Let $E$ be reflexive, i.e. the canonical embedding $i_E:E \to E'', x \mapsto i_E(x): E' \to \mathbb C, x' \mapsto x'(x)$ is surjective. This implies that $E \cong E''$, isometric, via $i_E$. If $F$ is also reflexive it follows from the fact:
$$T''\circ i_E= i_F \circ T,\text{so}: $$ That:
$$(1) i_F^{-1}\circ T''\circ i_E= T, \text{ and } (2) T'' = i_F \circ T \circ i_E^{-1}$$
So $T$ is "conjugate/similar" to its double adjoint, i.e. $"T = T''"$  up to isomorphism (this "equality" is defined as both criterias, $(1) + (2)$). Between hilbert spaces the adjoint operators are formally slightly different (but practically equal) defined, s.t. the double adjoint is (formally) equal to the original operator.
My question is now: Is it sufficient for $"(T=T'')"$ that $E$ is reflexive? One can identify $E \cong E''$ and $F \cong i_F(F) \subseteq F''$, subspace of $F''$, use the maps $T''\circ i_E, i_F\circ T$ and get the equation $T''\circ i_E= i_F \circ T$ (like above) $ (2)$ follows immediately, but the interesting part (the part i failed, but would immediately implie the hypothesis) is: why should $(T''\circ i_E)(E) \subseteq i_F(F)?$ Is it even true? Why not?
Unfortunately i ran out of ideas and would be very glad to hear any of yours!
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
$(2)$ follows from $E$ beeing reflexive but for the first one seems to need $F$ beeing reflexive too. To be honest i think that $"T=T'' "$ (so both criterias) in general only holds if $E,F$ are reflexive.
I tried to find some counter examples in spaces of complex valued sequences, but the statement didn't turn out to be false. Instead it kept beeing perfectly true in these particular examples...

How exactly do you interpret $T^{''}=T$? Is it not $T^{''} \circ i_E = i_F \circ T$?

The comment above from @EvangelopoulosFoivos made it clear. This is trivial, the answer is written in my question:
Since $T'' \circ i_E = i_F \circ T$ it follows:
$$(T'' \circ i_E)(E) \subseteq i_F(F)$$
Hence $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold, which gives us the "equality" (up to isomorphism) of $T,T''$ if $E$ is reflexive.
Note that this implies in particular, that $T = i_F^{-1} \circ T'' \circ i_E$, i.e. $T$ can always be expressed via $T''$/ as a restricted $T''$.
